# JAVA Generic on Entity Object From ArrayList<>

Tags: java, entity-framework

I would like to create a generic class if possible which will handle my entity objects

for example

Ive created a methods which has these arrays

```
public getNpvScheme(){
  ArrayList<Npvschemebyyear> plotsSchemeNPV = new ArrayList 
  (NpvschemebyyearFacade.findNPVPlots(strWhere, env));
    for(Npvschemebyyear npvMapData : plotsSchemeNPV ){
      jsonSummary.put("name", npvMapData.getRegion()) ;        
      jsonSummary.put("lat",  latLongArr.get(0));
      jsonSummary.put("long", latLongArr.get(1));
    }
 CODE....
}

public getMaintenanceScheme(){
  ArrayList<Maintenanceschemebyyear> plotsSchemeMaintenanceNPV = new ArrayList 
   (MaintenanceschemebyyearFacade.findNPVMaintenancePlots(strWhere, env));
     for(Maintenanceschemebyyear npvMapMaintenanceData : plotsSchemeMaintenanceNPV ){
       jsonSummary.put("name", npvMapData.getRegion()) ;
       jsonSummary.put("lat",  latLongArr.get(0));
       jsonSummary.put("long", latLongArr.get(1));
 }

 CODE....
}
```

what i would like to do is  pass npvMapData and npvMapMaintenanceData to a generic class which will allow me to read that entity object within my generic class and then my able to build the json with that class.

or if someone can suggest a better approach

Thanks

EDIT

I have, the issue i have is the generic class does not obtain entity object data.

below i my outline of my generic class

```
public abstract class PlotMaker<T> implements Icon{

    public JSONObject plots(){

        return null;
    };


    public JSONObject arrPlotMaker(PresentValue<?> pv){

        ArrayList<pv> arr = new ArrayList(); 


    };


}
```

ArrayList is where the issue is arising, i tried a few different way but no success.

To claify what i need,  i have a table called Maintenanceschemebyyear and a table called Npvschemebyyear which have entity classes behind them for there getter and setters.

i would like a general/generic method that allows me to pass these objects and allow me to see the entity object to call the getters and setter, which means i just create one JSONObject instead of 10 or so in each method.

Comment: Have you tried looking into generic types? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: I have, the issue i have is the generic class does not obtain entity object data. public abstract class PlotMaker<T> implements Icon{
    
    public JSONObject plots(){
       
        return null;
    };
   
    
    public JSONObject arrPlotMaker(PresentValue<?> pv){
        
        ArrayList<pv> arr = new ArrayList(); 
        return null;
        
    };

  
}

Comment: Whtat's `PresentValue` ?

Comment: Why do you even need generics for this?

Comment: PrensentValue is another generic class,

Comment: This is part of my question, i can pass the entity object of my table to a generic method or which can be used by any entity object

Comment: My question to `PresentValue` relates to the fact, that your edit does not seem related to `npvMapData` and `npvMapMaintenanceData` classes. Unless PresentValue encapsulates them. How do you pass your `...Data` classes to `PlotMaker` ? What does T represent? npvMapData? npvMapMaintenanceData? Or some base entity?

Comment: You will have to cast T object inside `PlotMaker` if you want to access `Data` classes members.